# Couchbase CAS NOT Working, when I upsert muli thread environment

Tags: couchbase

I use couchbase.
In order to count the API's call volume, count is added to the couchbase document per call.
The actual call amount and count did not match, so I checked.
The same count was duplicated and recorded.

```
if(bucket.exit(documentId)){
    bucket.getAndLock(documentId);
    count + 1
    if(bucket.unlock(documentId, cas)){
        bucket.upsert(JsonDocument);
        log.info(JsonDocument`s count);
    }
 } else{
     bucket.upsert(new JsonDocument);
 }

//under is log example
log1 - count : 1
log2 - count : 2
log3 - count : 2
log4 - count : 3
```

Upper process working in akka cluster.

I am wonder why same count is occur.

Pleas help me.

Comment: What server and client versions are you using?

Comment: This pseudocode isn't much to go on.  It's not clear when or if you're updating JsonDocument with the value of `count`, it's not clear if count is a thread-safe variable such as an AtomicInteger, and it appears that you're locking the document without reason since you upsert the document outside the lock.  It would be clearer if you could post the real code.  You almost certainly don't need pessimistic locking here anyway, you can use CAS and bucket.replace().
Bear in mind that you can use atomic counters - https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/howtos/kv-operations.html#atomic-counters

Comment: My Couchbase Server community 6.0.0 ver and client is 2.7.2 ver

Comment: @GrahamPople Thank you for your comment. It it helpful for me.
I solved this problem using replace().

Comment: @JingonPark good to hear :)